# querySelectorAll with boundary conditions

Tags: javascript, api, dom, selectors-api

`document.querySelectorAll` can be used to locate document elements with specific data attribute values.  For instance

```js
alert(document.querySelectorAll(".dk[data-kind='3']").length);
alert(document.querySelectorAll(".dk[data-kind>'3']").length);
```

```html
<div class='dk' data-kind='2'>A</div>
<div class='dk' data-kind='3'>B</div>
<div class='dk' data-kind='4'>C</div>
```

However, from what I can tell it is not possible to define selectors that use inequalities such as `data-kind>"3"` - run the code snippet here and attempting `querySelectorAll`with the boundary/inequality selector throws up an error.

jQuery provides mechanisms for doing such things albeit at the expense of a performance hit that is quite significant when dealing with mobile devices.

It would be a trivial matter to extract all `data-kind`elements and then testing their `kind` data for the boundary condition but I am wondering... - perhaps there is a way to write a clever query for `querySelectorAll` that I am not aware of?

Comment: *perhaps there is a way to write a clever query* No, there's not. However, you could consider using XPath (`document.evaluate`.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get all the elements having `data-kind` attribute. And filtering elements which satisfy certain condition.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dk[data-kind]"))
```

This statement will select all the elements having `dk` class and `data-kind` attribute. `Array.from` will convert the collection to Array so that array function can be directly used on it.

```
.filter(el => Number(el.dataset.kind) > 3)
```

This filter will filter the elements whose `data-kind` attribute value is greater than 3.

```js
var els = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dk[data-kind]")).filter(el => Number(el.dataset.kind) > 3);
console.log(els);
console.log(els.length);
```

```html
<div class='dk' data-kind='2'>A</div>
<div class='dk' data-kind='3'>B</div>
<div class='dk' data-kind='4'>C</div>
```

Comment: that's a nice answer!

Comment: Nice!  Thank you, very much!

Comment: A note for others running into this thread - I set out looking for a onliner solution and Tushar came up with a stellar one.  However, it requires ES6 so if your target is the WebView in older Android OS hybrid apps it will not work.  In any case, I did some jsPerf tests - the lowly `for` loop outperformed the array.from/array.filter combo by a factor of 10 (phones) and a factor of 20 (i7 desktop)